# reading values from text file

Tags: java, filereader

Please explain the compiler behaviour in the below code snippet. Consider the text file contains the following text TOBE and the corresponding byte values are 84, 79, 66, 69

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    byte inByte=(byte) buffInputFile.read();
    system.out.println(inByte);
}
```

When i run this snippet i get the following output 
84
79
66
69

But when i dubug at the for loop and step inside. The buffInputFile.read() shows me 84 at first and when assigned to inByte it is 79. and the output i get is

79,66,69,13 (13 is the carriage return).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you've got a debugger watch expression of `buffInputFile.read()` - which is reading the value from the stream in order to display it... but that value then isn't available when the method is executed *as part of the code*. You've read that byte from the stream, so the next call to `read()` will read the *next* byte, exactly as it's supposed to.

In general it's a very bad idea to execute methods with side effects within the debugger like this - it causes precisely this kind of confusion. If you just set a breakpoint on the line after the assignment, you can see the values that way.

In short: this isn't *compiler* behaviour going awry at all - it's the way you're using the debugger.

Comment: Thanks Jon... Is there any way i can overcome this.. Cause i need to debug and check..

Comment: Thanks Jon... That was very useful.. I presume the code is correct and the way i debugged was wrong....

Comment: @rozar: Yes. I assume you added a watch expression of `buffInputFile.read()` somewhere (it's not clear which debugger you're using) - basically, don't add watch expressions with side effects.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a bug, it's a feature. The `read` method returns the next byte from the stream and sets the internal marker to the next position.

When you inspect `buffInputFile.read()` with a debugger you effectively call that method and the debugger shows the actual value. *But* the marker has been set to the next position and so `inByte` will receive *the next* value from the stream.